# Camera Access from iframe of different domain not working

Tags: iframe, camera, cross-domain

I am trying to add site `https://example.com/` into `https://client.com`
I am using the following iframe:

```
<iframe src='https://example.com/' width='100%' height='675px' allow="geolocation *; microphone *; camera *; midi *; encrypted-media *" mozallowfullscreen='true' allowvr="yes" allowfullscreen="yes" ></iframe>
```

The camera is getting accessed on desktop but in mobile it's giving the following error:

**Call to requestPermission() failed, reason: Source frame did not have the same security origin as the main page.**

I have tried allow="camera `https://example.com/`;" also but in mobile (iphone safari and android chrome) its not getting the camera access.

Can anyone resolve the issue?

PS: we have added CORS headers in the abc.com server

Answer (score 0):

allow="geolocation microphone camera midi encrypted-media vr"
Add this attribute to iframe